# Basic process management under Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell, process

I've got the following elisp:

```
(setq proc (start-process "powershell" "*powershell*" "powershell.exe"))
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get `proc` to do anything.  For instance, in an normal shell, I can say `Get-Credential` and be presented with a GUI popup asking for a username/password.  What I imagine as the analog simply doesn't work:

```
(process-send-string proc "Get-Credential\n")
```

How can I get my process to do something?

---

I essentially want a shell that I can manipulate programmatically.

Comment: `stdin` and `stdout` in windows and unix are somehow incompatible. That is the reason for `cmdproxy.exe` in emacs-nt. Maybe you can route powershell through `cmdproxy.exe`? Didn't we both have already such a case???